# Parameterized classes and methods: making a method returns a correct type with java generics

Tags: java, generics

I have a class AbstractExtractionRules which constructor receives a ParserAPI object. The AbstractExtractionRules will be implemented using many different Parser APIs and each uses its own abstraction of 'Document'.

ParserAPI class has a parameterized type that represents the return type for the method parseDocument.

I want a way to use the ParserAPI in AbstractExtractionRules subclasses without the need of cast, leaving it in a more natural way.

I think with java generics, perhaps modifying the constructor parameter accordingly or modifying the call for `getParserAPI().parseDocument(htmlCode)` I can reach this, but I do not know how to do.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ExtractionRules<T> {
    List<T> extract(String htmlCode);
}

public interface ParserAPI<T> {
    T parseDocument(String htmlCode);
}

public abstract class AbstractExtractionRules <T> implements ExtractionRules <T> {
    private ParserAPI<?> parserAPI;

    public AbstractExtractionRules(ParserAPI<?> parserAPI) {
        this.parserAPI = parserAPI;
    }

    public ParserAPI<?> getParserAPI() {
        return parserAPI;
    }
}


public class RibeiraoVisitorRule extends AbstractExtractionRules <String> {

    public RibeiraoVisitorRule(ParserAPI<Document> parserAPI) {
        super(parserAPI);
    }

    @Override
    public List extract(String htmlCode) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();


        Document doc = (Document) getParserAPI().parseDocument(htmlCode);

        Elements submenu = doc.select("a.new_sub_menu");
        submenu.forEach(element1 -> {
            String href = element1.attr("abs:href");
            list.add(href.concat("&pageNum=VER-TUDO"));
        });
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass type from AbstractExtractionRules to ParserAPI:

```
public abstract class AbstractExtractionRules<A, T> implements ExtractionRules<T> {
    private ParserAPI<A> parserAPI;
```

Then you can call it without cast in concrete implementation class:

```
public class RibeiraoVisitorRule extends AbstractExtractionRules<Document, String> {

    @Override
    public List<String> extract(String htmlCode) {
        ...
        Document doc = getParserAPI().parseDocument("");
    }
```

Note that I also added passing type `T` to `ExtractionRules` interface. It affects the return type of `extract()` method. In your example you did not pass the type so return type of the method was `List`.

Comment: Is it the only way to achieve this? I had tought about this solution before, but I don't know if it it is a bit strange since Document is a parameter for the ParserAPI class. I mean... thus, would not be better to pass entire Parser API <Document> as type parameter? like: `public class RibeiraoVisitorRule extends AbstractExtractionRules <String, ParserAPI <Document >>`

Comment: @alexpfx it will look ugly: you either have to write extends AbstractExtractionRules<String, Document, ParserAPI<Document>> or extends AbstractExtractionRules<String, ParserAPI>.